# Best way to design multiple paginations in a REST API

Tags: rest, api, django

Let's suppose that I have a model named `Collection`. I can create a `collection`, this collection have two important fields: `shared_with_company`, `shared_list`.
currently I have an endpoint: `/collections`
and this endpoint returns something like it:

```json
    {
       shared_with_company:{collections: ..., count: 5}
       shared_list:{collections: ..., count: 12}
       my_collections:{collections: ..., count: 20}
    }
```

but, in the frontend the user want to paginate just my_collections or shared_list or shared_with_company. Should I create a specifics endpoints to each type of collections? Remember, everytime the user load the collections page will show 12 (max per page) collections of each (my_collections, shared etc.), and then he will be able to paginate it. I don't know if this is the best way to do it, I think a lot of users send 3 requests everytime the page is loaded.

Another approach: use an endpoint to load the initial page, and this endpoint will make one request to the first page and the paginations will be made with different endpoints.

I really don't know if there is a better approach or something like that.

I don't know if this can help, but I currently using Django + Django Rest Framework.

Comment: I'd say you're far better off having a standard pagination approach for all entities with their own endpoints. Mixing different entities in a single endpoint, each with their own pagination, sounds like a complicated mess IMO.

Comment: Doesn't Django have pagination facilities built in? I thought it did but my memory could be rusty......

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that if your sub-entities are going to be relatively short, it might be worth just downloading all the sub-objects and doing the pagination completely in the UI for those sub-entities.  That doesn't apply when the list becomes several hundred items long though.

Answer (score 2):

A REST API is supposed to be stateless, which means that the response given to a request cannot depend on (server-side) history of which requests I made earlier. For paging this means that the user must specify which page of a collection they want to receive.

With that in mind, it is easiest for everyone to have separate endpoints `/collections/shared_with_company`, `/collections/shared_list` and `/collections/my_collections` with each their independent paging.

In addition, you can offer a convenience endpoint (`/collections`) that returns the first page of each of the lists. That could be used by users to reduce the number of requests that need to be made initially.